# Sorting multidimensional array by value in alphabetical order

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to sort my array in alphabetical order so the result should be like this:

```
Inn Zoo
Leo Ann
Leo Zes
Sun Yog
```

I looked at all these examples but can't apply to my array below(older questions):

- [array sorting in DESC order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251045/array-sorting-in-desc-order)
- [sorting an array dynamically without knowing existing dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360416/sorting-an-array-dynamically-without-knowing-existing-dimensions)
- [Sort array by value alphabetically php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673259/sort-array-by-value-alphabetically-php)
- [PHP: How to sort values of an array in alphabetical order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080301/php-how-to-sort-values-of-an-array-in-alphabetical-order)

---

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Inn] => Array
                (
                    [Zoo] => Inn Zoo
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Sun] => Array
                (
                    [Yog] => Sun Yog
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Leo] => Array
                (
                    [Zes] => Leo Zes
                )

        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [Leo] => Array
                (
                    [Ann] => Leo Ann
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: why can't you apply it to this example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sort a multidimensional array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: most likely because he is using the name as the key for his array. You would probably just have to do something like array_keys and get the first value then sort by that.

Comment: Your array structure is very weird. Why are you using names as keys instead of using uniform keys like `first_name` and `last_name`?

Comment: Can the subarrays ever have more than one element?

Comment: OK, I changed the structure to `$key=>$value` by concatenating `name, surname and Full name`. `asort()` finished the job. Thanks all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
array
(
    [0] => Inn|Zoo|Inn Zoo
    [1] => Sunn|Yog|Sun Yog
    [2] => Leo|Zes|Leo Ann
    [3] => Leo|Ann|Leo Zes
)

asort($list);

array
(
    [0] => Inn|Zoo|Inn Zoo
    [3] => Leo|Ann|Leo Zes
    [2] => Leo|Zes|Leo Ann
    [1] => Sunn|Yog|Sun Yog
)
```

Comment: Contributor of the downvote - how do we know that you're not just one of those who swing around to randomly down vote posts for fun?